# Minimum number of swaps to make two arrays strictly increasing

Tags: dynamic-programming, arrays

I'm trying to understand the solution of the following problem ([LC 801](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-swaps-to-make-sequences-increasing/)):

> Given two arrays, A and B, of the same nonzero length, find the minimum number of swaps (A[i] <--> B[i]) to make A and B strictly increasing.
>
> The solution is guaranteed to exist for the given input data.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: A = [1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6], B = [7, 8, 3, 10, 12, 13]
>
> Output: 1 (swap 9 and 3)

The solutions posted by others consider a `dp` array, of size [2, A.size()], which is filled as follows:

```
int N = static_cast<int>(A.size());
std::vector<std::vector<int>> dp(2, std::vector<int>(N, N));

for (int ii = 1; ii < N; ++ii) {
  if (A[ii - 1] > A[ii] && B[ii - 1] > B[ii]) {
    dp[0][ii] = std::min(dp[0][ii], dp[0][ii - 1]);
    dp[1][ii] = std::min(dp[1][ii], dp[1][ii - 1] + 1);
  }
  if (A[ii] > B[ii - 1] && B[ii] > A[ii - 1]) {
    dp[0][ii] = std::min(dp[0][ii], dp[1][ii - 1]);
    dp[1][ii] = std::min(dp[1][ii], dp[0][ii - 1] + 1);
  }
}

return std::min(dp[0][N - 1], dp[1][N - 1]);
```

How to think / develop the idea for the solution?

It is clear that in the case the monotony is broken, i.e. A[ii] <= A[ii - 1] we need to swap, but, from trying a few test cases, this is not the optimal way to do the swaps.

Answer (score 1):

$dp[b][i]$ denotes the minimum number of swaps needed to make the first $i$ elements of both arrays strictly increasing where $b$ is a boolean flag denoting whether we've swapped $A[i]$ and $B[i]$ (or $\infty$ if this minimum doesn't exist).

The key observation is that we only care about what $A[i-1]$ and $B[i-1]$ are when calculating $dp[0/1][i]$. This means that we can calculate $dp[0/1][i]$ using only $A[i-1]$, $B[i-1]$, $A[i]$, $B[i]$ and $dp[0/1][i-1]$ in $\mathcal O(1)$ time. (The recurrences are shown in the code you posted).

The answer is clearly $\min(dp[0/1][N])$, and this solution runs in $\mathcal O(N)$ time.